# What is the "purpose of concealment"?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah

I am interested in different understandings of the concept of תכלית העלם "purpose of concealment". For instance, you see R' Avraham Abulafia using this expression: והורכב על זה מאותיות ההעלמה, ולא היה נעלם **תכלית העלם** אפילו המשכילים בעיינם (Ohr HaSechel, החלק ו' סימני אותיות). Also, וכמו שמהותו נעלם תכלית העלם, כן מציאותו נעלם **תכלית ההעלם**. ומציאות זולתו תלוי במציאותו, לפי שכולם קנו המציאות ממנו (R' Yosef Albo, Sefer HaIkkarim, הבנת ה' בדרך שלילת התארים). Or even, צריך שידע עוד כי קודם אצילות המדות הנזכרות היו המדות נעלמות בו **תכלית העלם** ויחוד שלא יצדק בהם ציור ונקודה כלל אלא הם מתאחדות בו (Ramak, Ohr Ne'erav 6:1), etc.
Any thoughts?

These are my thoughts to add more context:

Consider the seder *histalshelut* wherefrom the lights were issued and the kelim were seen and their contents were identified and the *klipot* were made. And the *ikkar* of this seder is to clarify the dross from the holiness, as it is impossible for holiness to become clarified in a higher place (*Atzilut*) since it is a process that must be done via *birur* in the lower world of *Asiyah*. And this will continue until the end of time when holiness will be clarified from the *klipot*, and the *kedusha* will return to ascend to its chosen place for the purpose of *birur*. But not as before, where good and evil were mixed for the **purpose of concealment** (i.e., concealing the *Ohr Ein Sof* so Its revelation can be gradual and appropriate for each level and degree of the realities of the *olamot*). This work cannot be done unless by the creation of the worlds and their chaining together. And from this you will understand more what he means to say to clarify the dross from the *kedusha*, etc., and that the *kedusha* will return to rise above to the place of clarification in the purpose of *birur*.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could please provide some introductory context for greater clarity @SimpleYid

Comment: Yes, without context it is hard but I suspect this is similar to p'tach Eliyahu, Hashem reveals Himself through concealing Himself. Lmashal, in order to see the sun, we must conceal it with filters. People reveal themselves in what they say, but even more so in what they _don't_ say.

Comment: I just added material to my original question. Regards.

Comment: @SimpleYid yes, that's referring to the idea I wrote in my above comment. Bli neder I'll write it up into an answer next week, it's worth it. Shabbat shalom

Comment: Yep! Said differently because of my "orientation", but essentially you are on a similar path. A gut Shabbos.